# knitr HTML output too large

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have been using `rmarkdown`/`knitr`'s `knit to html` capability to generate html code for some blogs. I've found it extremely helpful and convenient, but have been running into some problems lately with file size.

When I knit a script that has graphics that use shapefiles or `ggmap` images, the html file gets too big for the blog host to make sense of it (I've tried with both blogger and wordpress). I believe this has to do with the relatively large data.frames/files that are the shapefiles/`ggmap` being put into html form. Is there anything I can do to get a smaller html file that can be parsed by a blog host?

For reference, the html output from an rmarkdown script with one graphic using a `ggmap` layer, a layer of shapefiles and some data is 1.90MB, which is too big for blogger or wordpress to handle in html input. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Below are 3 different options to help you reduce the file size of HTML files with encoded images.

---

## 1. Optimize an existing HTML file

You can run [this Python script](https://gist.github.com/slowkow/d0cfa4c21ca7e72f6fed4a1d82112b94) on an existing HTML file. The script will:

- decode the base64 encoded images
- run [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) to optimize the images
- re-encode the optimized images as base64

Usage:

```
python optimize_html.py infile.html
```

It writes output to `infile-optimized.html`.

---

## 2. Use the built-in knitr hook for optimizing PNG images

[knitr](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) 1.15 includes a hook called `hook_optipng` that will run the [optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) program on generated PNG files to reduce file size.

Here is a `.Rmd` example (taken from: [knitr-examples/035-optipng.Rmd](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/035-optipng.Rmd)):

````
# 035-optipng.Rmd

This demo shows you how to optimize PNG images with `optipng`.

```{r setup}
library(knitr)
knit_hooks$set(optipng = hook_optipng)
```

Now we set the chunk option `optipng` to a non-`NULL` value,
e.g. `optipng=''`, to activate the hook. This string is passed to
`optipng`, so you can use `optipng='-o7'` to optimize more heavily.

```{r use-optipng, optipng=''}
library(methods)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
qplot(rnorm(1e3), rnorm(1e3))
```
````

---

## 3. Write your own knitr hook for any image optimizer

[Writing your own hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/) is also quite easy, so I wrote a hook that calls the [pngquant](https://pngquant.org/) program. I find that `pngquant` runs faster, and the output files are smaller and look better.

Here is a `.R` example that defines and uses `hook_pngquant` (taken from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/slowkow/6c57fdbbde4a3b980045661d988c6f59)).

```
#' ---
#' title: "pngquant demo"
#' author: "Kamil Slowikowski"
#' date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
#' output:
#'   html_document:
#'     self_contained: true
#' ---

#+ setup, include=FALSE
library(knitr)

# Functions taken from knitr/R/utils.R
all_figs = function(options, ext = options$fig.ext, num = options$fig.num) {
  fig_path(ext, options, number = seq_len(num))
}
in_dir = function(dir, expr) {
  if (!is.null(dir)) {
    owd = setwd(dir); on.exit(setwd(owd))
  }
  wd1 = getwd()
  res = expr
  wd2 = getwd()
  if (wd1 != wd2) warning(
    'You changed the working directory to ', wd2, ' (probably via setwd()). ',
    'It will be restored to ', wd1, '. See the Note section in ?knitr::knit'
  )
  res
}
is_windows = function() .Platform$OS.type == 'windows'
in_base_dir = function(expr) {
  d = opts_knit$get('base.dir')
  if (is.character(d) && !file_test('-d', d)) dir.create(d, recursive = TRUE)
  in_dir(d, expr)
}

# Here is the code you can modify to use any image optimizer.
hook_pngquant <- function(before, options, envir) {
  if (before)
    return()
  ext = tolower(options$fig.ext)
  if (ext != "png") {
    warning("this hook only works with PNG")
    return()
  }
  if (!nzchar(Sys.which("pngquant"))) {
    warning("cannot find pngquant; please install and put it in PATH")
    return()
  }
  paths = all_figs(options, ext)
  in_base_dir(lapply(paths, function(x) {
    message("optimizing ", x)
    cmd = paste(
      "pngquant",
      if (is.character(options$pngquant)) options$pngquant,
      shQuote(x)
    )
    message(cmd)
    (if (is_windows())
      shell
      else system)(cmd)
    x_opt = sub("\\.png$", "-fs8.png", x)
    file.rename(x_opt, x)
  }))
  return()
}

# Enable this hook in this R script.
knit_hooks$set(
  pngquant = hook_pngquant
)

#' Here we set the chunk option `pngquant='--speed=1 --quality=0-50'`,
#' which activates the hook.

#+ use-pngquant, pngquant='--speed=1 --quality=0-50'
library(methods)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
qplot(rnorm(1e3), rnorm(1e3))
```

I prefer to write my reports in R scripts (`.R`) instead of R markdown documents (`.Rmd`). See http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/ for more information on how to do that.

Comment: `hook_pngquant` is available natively in `knitr` since version 1.15.1

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do would be to not use embedded image and other resources. To achieve this, you can set the `self_contained` option in the YAML header for your document to `false`, e.g.:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
---
```

More info here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html

Comment: Is there a way to embed the images but not the rest of the stuff (like all the data points etc)? Not sure of these can be separated really but that would be ideal. Thanks for the point in this direction.

Comment: What do you mean when you say data points? When you render a knitr/RMarkdown document, the only thing that goes into the HTML are the text/code in the document, and anything printed or plotted. So, unless you are explicitly printing the data frame to the screen, the datapoints themselves will only appear indirectly in your plots. If you are using SVG or something similar, then the images will be large since they are storing each datapoint, but if you are just using the defaults (PNG), then that should not be an issue.

Comment: I thought that the contents of each data frame were somehow stored in the knitted html, like the html code is the whole process of running the calculations, etc. I only thought so because the html file is considerably bigger than the knitted word document. Clearly I'm not very familiar with these inner workings, nor with html, so thanks for your help.

Comment: @moman822 Jupyter/Ipython notebooks do indeed store some of the intermediate data structures in JSON, but that is not the case for knitr. The difference in filesize likely has to do with different default image formats for html/doc output, as well as external javascript and CSS files which get embedded in the stand-alone html output files. 

By generating a non-standalone version of the HTML, you can also more easily determine how big each of the images are, and if there is one that is particularly large, you can try changing the image dimensions, format, etc. to reduce its size.