# How can I show a large map to html?

Tags: dictionary, r-markdown, export

I'm trying to knit to html a document, but it seems that the map I have created is too big to be knitted, is there a way to fix that?

I have tried to delete all the NA data of all the variables.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815784/knitr-html-output-too-large) might contain answers for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.